# Creating pandas DataFrame from numpy array leads to strange errors

Tags: python, pandas

The short of the long is that DataFrames are spitting out endianess errors when I try to create them from functional numpy arrays. Here is a pastebin, more details below:
http://pastebin.com/Sdg9EM61

In my field we store data in .FIT format, which is a binary format (this may be useful info later)

I don't really know how to address this following few lines of code and error.

```
d = fits.getdata('file.fit')
d2 = np.array(d)
```

Then you can do cool tricks with this like:

```
d2[d2['key1'] > 10.]
d2[['key1', 'key2']]
```

etc.

When I convert it to a pandas DataFrame

```
d3 = pandas.DataFrame(d2)
```

things start to get weird. The column names have changed for example:

```
d3.columns
```

returns

```
Index([u'key1', u'key2'], dtype='object')
```

with this new u in front of every column name as opposed to

```
d2.dtype
```

returning

```
dtype([('key1', '>i4'), ('key2', 'S19')])
```

although the data types look ok in the dataframe when you do d3.dtypes instead of d3.columns...

Anyways, the DataFrame has all the data and preserves the data types and I can print out characterizing data and such, but as soon as I try to do something like this:

```
d3[d3['key1'] > 10.]
```

I get a monster error about endianess:

```
ValueError: Big-endian buffer not supported on little-endian compiler
```

Any insight as to what this means and how to fix?

Comment: seems related: https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/1156

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, The FITS file is in fact the issue. Turns out FITS are all big endian while pandas and scipy and stuff tend to assume little endian (I have no idea what this endian business is, just summarizing a thread) and this causes some weird issues apparently (that I've never seen until looking at pandas).

The solution I have found is:

```
d = fits.getdata('data.fit')
df=pd.DataFrame(np.array(d).byteswap().newbyteorder())
```

The solution was located here:
https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/1156

Comment: Endians are about bit orders. If the data is written in reverse or not.