# How to make a.fits.gz file into a pandas DataFrame 'ValueError: Big-endian buffer not supported on little-endian compiler'

Tags: python, pandas, astropy, astronomy

I have the file `'3dhst.v4.1.5.master.fits.gz'`, which I want to open and make into a DataFrame. I want to pull out a selection of the columns from this, which I will then merge with another DataFrame. I have attempted the following:

```
import astropy
from astropy.io import fits
master = fits.open('3dhst.v4.1.5.master.fits.gz')
masterdf = pd.DataFrame(master[1].data)
masterdf = masterdf[['grism_id' , 'field' , 'ra' , 'dec' , 'z_best', 'z_best_s' ,  'z_spec' , 
'z_peak_phot' , 'z_max_grism']]
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Big-endian buffer not supported on little-endian compiler
```

Which is an error message I've seen before with this file, and still do not understand why. The astropy documentation says 'The `open()` function will seamlessly open FITS files that have been compressed with gzip, bzip2 or pkzip. Note that in this context we are talking about a FITS file that has been compressed with one of these utilities (e.g., a .fits.gz file).' If I run just the opening of the file I get no errors. I also tried to open the file using:

```
with gzip.open('3dhst.v4.1.5.master.fits.gz') as f:
     master = fits.open(f)
```

This returns an empty response to `master[0].header`, so this approach fails.

Comment: The exception is probably not due to the compression, but that's hard to say without the complete traceback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating pandas DataFrame from numpy array leads to strange errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283836/creating-pandas-dataframe-from-numpy-array-leads-to-strange-errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `Table` class from Astropy is probably a better option, it has a method to convert to a pandas `DataFrame`:

```py
from astropy.table import Table
t = Table.read('3dhst.v4.1.5.master.fits.gz')
t = t[['grism_id' , 'field' , 'ra' , 'dec' , 'z_best', 'z_best_s' ,  'z_spec' , 'z_peak_phot' , 'z_max_grism']]
df = t.to_pandas()
```

https://docs.astropy.org/en/latest/table/pandas.html