# Apply multi conditional mask to dataframe

Tags: pandas, mask

I need to apply a mask to my sparse matrix `df` and then convert bools to 1.0, like so:

```
link = 16.0 
mask = (df<=link) 
# convert lesser values to 1
df = df.where(mask, 1.0)
```

---

This works. But now I need to use another condition for masking, like so:

```
mask = (df<=link) & (df!=0.0)
```

or:

```
mask = ((df<=link) & (df!=0.0))
```

But this throws me the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

---

EDIT:

`df.dtypes` print:

```
0       >f4
1       >f4
2       >f4
3       >f4
4       >f4
       ... 
1853    >f4
1854    >f4
1855    >f4
1856    >f4
1857    >f4
Length: 1858, dtype: object
```

---

This is how I get my matrix:

```
from astropy.io import fits

with fits.open('matrix_CEREBELLUM_large.fits') as data:
    df = pd.DataFrame(data[0].data)
```

link to matrix:

https://cosmosimfrazza.myfreesites.net/cosmic-web-and-brain-network-datasets

---

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you include the creation script for `df` so as your error is replicable?

Comment: sure. I've linked the adjacent matrix in the question.

Comment: Length: 1858, dtype: object

Comment: none whatsoever

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp I've edited my question with dtypes

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp just edited my question. thanks for you valuable effort. will upvote any try.

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp you must download ADJACENT MATRIX file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the line

```
brain_mask = (df<=brain_Llink & df<=brain_Llink!=0)
```

there's two subtle bugs: `df <= brain_Llink != 0`, and operator precedence: `a <= b & c != d` takes precedence `a <= (b & c) != d` but you want `(a <= b) & (c != d)`. So fix with:

```py
brain_mask = ((df <= brain_Llink) & (df != 0))

#or

brain_mask = df.le(brain_Llink) & df.ne(0)
```

---

If you get an error about

```
ValueError: Big-endian buffer not supported on little-endian compiler
```

which may lead you to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283836/creating-pandas-dataframe-from-numpy-array-leads-to-strange-errors) then this will fix it:

```py
from astropy.io import fits

with fits.open('matrix_CEREBELLUM_large.fits') as data:
                                  # change from big-endian to little-endian
    df = pd.DataFrame(data[0].data.byteswap().newbyteorder())
```

Comment: upvoted. this converts f4 to float32, and it is good practice, but still the probloem resides in the double condition passed to mak. it works with one condition and breaks with two...thanks anyway